# Counting days at the place

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am working on the crystal report Xi and my problem is in my report I have to show the count of the days patient spend on one place, they can get transfer any number of times or they don't get transfer even one time. So every time they transferred from their admission to discharge I want to count of days on that place the patient spend.

```
PatID    Admission     Discharge    Place   TransferPlace   TransferDate
121      05\06\2013    06\01\2013    102     105             05\10\2013
121                                  105     101             05\20\2013
121                                  101     108             05\25\2013
```

Here I just created a data the patient first transfer on 05\10\2013 from 102 to 105 that means he was at 102 since he got admitted (4 days) and in 105 he was for 10 days.
I hope it should be clear.**

Answer (score 0):

Try [DATEDIFF()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) function it will return the date difference

Comment: Datediff will not work I tried that I want the place and the count of days. This did not come out as table manner. I have to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between dates you use the DateDiff function. In your case you want to get the amount of days between the dates, you would use:

```
DateDiff(day, {Admission.Date}, {Transfer.Date})
```

{Admission.Date} and {Transfer.Date} are the date fields you would be using in your report.

EDIT:

So I think you can make this work using the PREVIOUS function in Crystal. Try something like:

```
if isNull(previous({Transfer.Date}) then
DateDiff(day, {Admission.Date}, {Transfer.Date}) else
DateDiff(day, previous({Transfer.Date}), {Transfer.Date})
```

You could also go the other way by using the NEXT function.

Comment: I know what you want to say but it's not that easy as you are saying. For date diff I need 2 date column if they are admission to transfer or transfer to discharge it's easy but between two transfer I need two column for transfer date and show that date with place where was that person till that time. for every patient it's different someone has no transfer someone has more then 5. in C# we can do looping and try it here in crystal how should I do it.

Comment: After seeing your update to the table you will have to approach it by using the PREVIOUS function. For the first line of data you will do the calculation using Admission and TransferDate (see original answer). For all other lines of data the calculation will be DateDiff(day, Previous{TransferDate}, {TransferDate}). The trick will be an if/else statement that checks whether there is a previous  Transfer Date. Does that make sense?

Comment: Before I tried with the NEXT function and then did if/else statement but did not check they have transfer date or not. and How will I show the place he was there till this date and that many days.

Comment: See edit to my answer and let me know if that works.

Comment: It didn't work for all the people. But that I think I have to figure it out. thanks

Comment: It didn't work for all the people. But that I think I have to figure it out. thanks                                                               one more thing you helped so where should I go mark it.

Comment: If it helped you solve the problem, you can mark as answered (click check-mark next to question), or upvote (arrow up next to question).